# crawling web using python and selenium tools

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, spyder, pyhook

while importing the selenium library I am getting error, at following line of cod

> from selenium import webdriver

I am seeing following error:

> No module named 'selenium

I have installed selenium using following command

> pip install selenium

But it doesn't work. i also have tried to do this in my command prompt but it still the same error.
Anybody can help me to solve this please?

> pip install -e git+https://github.com/cmwslw/selenium-crawler.git#egg=selenium-crawler".

Thank you.

Comment: did you run `from selenium import webdriver` from python in command line, did it show the same result?

Comment: yes i did. 
i run from command line and from spyder tools, but it show the same result.

Comment: which version of selenium, python and OS you are using?

Comment: i use 2.32 selenium version and 2.7 python version.